# How to make a directive link function to run only once

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive in angular:

```
function myDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element) {
          console.warn("my directive);
        }
    };
}

angular.module('myapp').directive('myDirective', myDirective);
```

And I use `ng-if` on the html tag that uses the directive.
I want to make the link here run only once. But it does every other time the ng-if is triggered.

I trying passing an argument to the `scope`And so use the two way binding to set it to false, like this:

```
function myDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            shouldRun: "="
        }
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element) {
          $scope.shouldRun = false
          console.warn("my directive);
        }
    };
}
angular.module('myapp').directive('myDirective', myDirective);
```

And on the element itslef use: `<div my-directive shouldRun="true"></div>`
But it does not wark.

Could anyone help please?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

I will try to be more clear:
I have a div, with ng-if directive on it. Inside, I have yet another directive. this directive, expands the width of the element on which it is defined.
I click a button to trigger the ng-if.

First time - everything works fine.

I click the button again - element is gone.

Another click - element being rendered again.

Only, this time, when the link function is called, it somehow REMEMBERS the previous EXPANDED width.

For example:

```
<div ng-if="vm.myCondition">
  <div my-directive style="width:100px;"></div>
</div>

link: function(scope, elem) {
    console.warn($(elem).width());
    $(elem).width($(elem).width() * 1.1);
}
```

first print would be 100;
Second time the directive is being created it STARTS by being 110! and that is what I get in the console.

Yes, if I use timeout of 0 - it works fine. But it does not look fine.

Comment: Link should run every time the directive is compiled. So if you are using ng-if then it will run every time that expression is true. Maybe you want ng-show/ng-hide instead? You might include in your question what you are actually trying to accomplish to help show where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Every time your ng-if evaluates to true, it will render this directive (more specifically, a new instance of this directive). It sounds like you need to control this with your ng-if.

You example:

```
<div my-directive shouldRun="true"></div>
```

Instead, use logic in your controller to conditionally render with

```
<div my-directive ng-if="..."></div>
```

Since you are having trouble with ng-if, you probably need to add other conditions like

Note that whenever ng-if evaluates to false and then to true again, your directive will be rerendered. This is logic that should be in your controller.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I want to accomplish. I need the ng-if to run every time.
I just want the link function to be called only once at the first run.

Comment: Can you wrap it with another ng-if?

Comment: @Yogev it sounds like you are using your directive wrong if you want the link to only run once ever. Without the link running your directive doesn't compile; if your directive doesn't compile then you have no directive.

Comment: @MatthewGreen Thanks. But it's not true.
My directive modifies the html tag css. I need that to happen only once.
For example, if I add pixels to the width, they are being re-added over and over every other time the directive is rendered, and it gets bigger and bigger.

The ng-if is actually on the wrapping div:
<div ng-if="..." > <div my-directive> </div> </div>

Comment: @Yogev without more information, we can't help. What are the conditions for your ng-if? How is this being handled in your controller? It sounds like you don't have a complete understanding of directives and how they work.

Comment: @Yogev it is true. [It sounds like you are asking the wrong question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) For example, why do you have a directive wrapped in a ng-if modifying the top level CSS? Why not a directive on the html tag or a directive for the html tag itself? What led you to believe this is the solution you need?

Comment: Thanks for the professional criticizing and analysis.
Now If we focus on the question it self, please? 
I edited the question . Thank you