# ng-if remembers the state of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a div which has a `ng-if` directive on it.
Nested in it, I have yet another div with another directive. this directive, expands the width of the element on which it is defined.

1. I click a button to trigger the ng-if.
2. First time - everything works fine. directive is being created as
   expected.
3. I click the button again - element is gone.
4. Another click - element being rendered again, Only this time, when
   the link function is called, it somehow "remembers" the previous
   **expanded** width of the element.

For example:

```
#myDiv {
   width: 100px;
}

<div ng-if="vm.myCondition">
  <div id="myDiv" my-directive></div>
</div>

link: function(scope, elem) {
   console.warn($(elem).width());
   $(elem).width($(elem).width() * 1.1);
}
```

First print would be 100.
Second time the directive is being created it **starts** by being 110! and **that** is what I get in the console. 110.

Yes, if I use timeout of 0 - it works fine. But it does not look fine. You see a bink in the element's width.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: show us a fiddle where to reproduce the problem. Where are you setting myCondition to false ? What is my-directive ? In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pLdp64w2/ I can't reproduce the problem so we need little bit more code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a directive link function to run only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957344/how-to-make-a-directive-link-function-to-run-only-once)